# Determine the solution set of an inequality by transformations and sign table

Tags: inequality

$$
\frac{x^{2}-x-2}{x-1} >0
$$

"What is the solution set of the inequality? Show by doing appropriate transformations, and through a sign table."

I would like to know how to solve this question, the solution is below, but I am not understanding how they arrived at this answer. Could someone simplify the explanation? Especially the sign table?

1.
$$
\begin{gathered}\frac{x^{2}-x-2}{x-1} >0\\ \Leftrightarrow \left( x^{2}-x-2<0\  \wedge \  x-1>0\right)  \vee \left( x^{2}-x-2>0\  \wedge \  x-1>0\right)  \\ \Leftrightarrow \left( -1<x<2\  \wedge \  x<1\right)  \vee \left( \left( x<-1\  \vee x>2\right)  \wedge x>1\right)  \\ \Leftrightarrow -1<x<1\  \vee x>2\\ \end{gathered} 
$$

The solution set, S, is
$$
S=\{ x\in R|-1<x<1\  \vee x>2\} 
$$

And through the sign table we get:
2.
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}x&&-1&&1&&2&\\ x^{2}-x-2&+&0&-&-&-&0&+\\ x-1&-&-&-&0&+&+&+\\ \frac{x^{2}-x-2}{x-1} &-&0&+&nd&-&0&+\end{array} 
$$

Thus, the solution set, S, will be
$$
S=\{ x\in R|-1<x<1\  \vee x>2\} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I am not happy with how this material was apparently presented to the OP (i.e. Original Poster, AKA Math student).  It seems unnecessarily convoluted.  So, I will provide an alternative way of making sense out of the concepts.

Given two well defined functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, the only values of $(x)$ that will satisfy the inequality

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 0,$$

are those values of $x$ that satisfy both of the following requirements:

- $g(x) \neq 0.$ 
  If the value of $x$ does not satisfy this requirement, then the expression $~\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}~$ is not well defined.
- Either 
  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both positive 
  or 
  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both negative.

Note that although the first bullet point requirement is actually implied by the second bullet point requirement, I still listed it separately, for **emphasis**.

Further, for the second bullet point, as illustrative examples,

- $\dfrac{7}{3} > 0, ~~\dfrac{-7}{-3} > 0.$
- $\dfrac{-7}{3} < 0, ~~\dfrac{7}{-3} < 0.$

In this particular instance, 
$f(x) = x^2 - x - 2,~~$ and 
$g(x) = (x - 1)$.

---

So, since $g(x)$ is easier to analyze than $f(x)$, that will be the first step.  Here, you have three cases to consider:

- $x = 1 \implies g(x) = 0.$ 
  Per the discussion, $x = 1$ is automatically an **outlawed value**.
- $x > 1 \implies g(x) > 0.$ 
  So, in this instance, you will be looking for all values of $x$ such that $~x > 1~$ **and** $f(x) > 0.$
- $x < 1 \implies g(x) < 0.$ 
  So, in this instance, you will be looking for all values of $x$ such that $~x < 1~$ **and** $f(x) < 0.$

---

At this point, there is no avoiding that the behavior of the function $f(x)$ needs to be analyzed.  Fortunately, $f(x)$ is only a 2nd degree polynomial (rather than a polynomial of higher degree).

Although the presented question did not specifically outlaw using Calculus to study the behavior of $f(x)$, I feel that in this problem, it will be more effective if Calculus is **outlawed**.

One approach to the problem would be to attempt to graph the function $f(x)$.  Then, you would study the behavior of the portion of the graph where $x > 1$ and the behavior of the graph where $x < 1.$

If (for example) $f(x)$ was a polynomial of degree higher than $(2)$, and if Calculus methods were outlawed, then this might be the way to go.  Since $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $(2)$, the behavior of $f(x)$ can readily be scrutinized by Algebra.

The method to be used, *completing the square*, is similar to the method used to derive the quadratic equation.

Anyway, to analyze the behavior of the function $f(x)$, the first step is to ask:

with $f(x) = x^2 - x - 2$,

what first degree polynomial $(x - r)$ will be such that

the first two terms in $(x - r)^2 = x^2 - x.$

Since $(x - r)^2 = x^2 - 2rx + r^2$, you need $(2r)$ to equal $(1)$.

This means that you begin analyzing the behavior of $f(x)$ by first constructing the function

$$\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = x^2 - x + \frac{1}{4}.$$

This implies that

$$f(x) = \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{9}{4}. \tag1 $$

Therefore,

$$f(x) > 0 \iff \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 > \frac{9}{4} = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2. \tag2 $$

Also,

$$f(x) < 0 \iff \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 < \frac{9}{4} = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2. \tag3 $$

So, the behavior of $f(x)$ has been reduced to determining which values of $x$, where $~x \neq 1,~$ satisfy the inequalities in (2) and (3), above.

In order to do this, the OP needs the following Algebraic result:

Given two real values $R$ and $S$, where $~S > 0~,$you have that

- $R^2 > S^2$ if and only if 
  either 
  $R > S$ 
  or 
  $R < -S.$
- $R^2 < S^2$ if and only if 
  $R < S$ 
  and 
  $R > -S.$

---

Using the above Algebraic result, the behavior of $f(x)$, with respect to the inequalities in (2) and (3) can now be analyzed.

- $f(x) > 0~$ if and only if 
  $\displaystyle \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right) > \frac{3}{2}$ 
  or 
  $\displaystyle \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right) < \frac{-3}{2}.$
- $f(x) < 0~$ if and only if 
  $\displaystyle -\frac{3}{2} < \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right) < \frac{3}{2}.$

These results may be re-expressed as

- $f(x) > 0~$ if and only if 
  $\displaystyle x > 2$ 
  or 
  $\displaystyle x < -1.$
- $f(x) < 0~$ if and only if 
  $\displaystyle -1 < x < 2.$

---

Now, it is time to put this together with the behavior of $g(x)$.  The simplest way to do this is to break the analysis of the behavior of $g(x)$ into the two cases of $g(x) > 0$ and $g(x) < 0.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1} ~g(x) > 0}$

Case 1 will apply if and only if $x > 1.$

So, in Case 1, you are looking for values of $(x)$ such that

- $x > 1$
- $f(x) > 0.$

From the analysis, this will specifically be represented by those values of $(x)$ such that

$$~x > 2.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2} ~g(x) < 0}$

Case 2 will apply if and only if $x < 1.$

So, in Case 2, you are looking for values of $(x)$ such that

- $x < 1$
- $f(x) < 0.$

From the analysis, this will specifically be represented by those values of $(x)$ such that

$$-1 < x < 1.$$

---

Putting Case 1 and Case 2 together, the entire solution set of the inequality

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 0$$

will be those values of $(x)$ where

- Either $~x > 2$
- Or $~-1 < x < 1.$

Answer (score 1):

The continuous function
$$\frac{(x-2)(x+1)}{x-1}$$
may only change its sign at its zeroes, $x=2$ or $x=-1$, or where it's not defined, $x=1$.  All three linear factors of the fraction have an odd multiplicity, hence a change of sign will occur at the zeroes of each factor.  As for $x=0$ the fraction is positive, it will be positive for $-1<x<1$, negative for $x<-1$ and for $1<x<2$ and positive for $x>2$.